# One-to-one correspondence between prime ideal lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ and $B\otimes_A\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> Let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then the prime ideals of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $B\otimes_A\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$.

I don't know how to start. Could you give any hints? $A,B$ are both commutative rings and $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is a field of fraction of $A/\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Here's the idea: when does an ideal $P$ of $B$ lie over $\mathfrak{p}$? Well, $P$ must contain every element of $f(\mathfrak{p})$, hence the ideal $Q := \mathfrak{p}B$ of $B$. The prime ideals of $B$ containing $Q$ are in bijection with the prime ideals of $B/QB$, so you might be tempted to say that the primes of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $B/QB$. But this is wrong: there may be primes of $B$ containing $Q$ whose contraction to $A$ is bigger than $\mathfrak{p}$. You need to find a way to "ignore" these primes in your calculation.

Comment: So what can you do? For any commutative ring $R$ and any multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$, the primes of $S^{-1}R$ are in bijection with the primes of $R$ which do not meet $S$, i.e. whose intersection with $S$ is trivial. You need to ignore the primes of $B$ which contain (the image of) some element of $A$ which is not in $Q$. This corresponds to localizing at the multiplicative subset of $B$ given by $f(A \setminus \mathfrak{p})$. What remains is to figure out the relationship between what I've said and $B \otimes_{A} \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$. I leave this to you - good luck!

Comment: *Sorry, that should read "...some element of $A$ which is not in $\mathfrak{p}$."